# How to apply gradient color on frame created in tcltk (ttk)?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

Is it possible to get gradient color in frame which created in ttk in tcl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get a gradient color if you:

- Use a gradient color on OSX Aqua, which has a more sophisticated coloring scheme that Tk plugs into partially, or
- Use a style that paints the background using a photo image that has a gradient in it, or
- Write a custom style engine that does everything itself.

The first is very platform specific (and I don't know the details), the second is taking you into the complex world of custom image styles, and the third involves *deep* voodoo that is definitely beyond what I know!

Comment: Another choice is to use a canvas rather than a frame, and draw the gradient as a series of lines.